# How to group python list first by id then by release date

Tags: python, json

I'm new to this site and for my first question, the request is kinda specific, but I'll try to generalize my question.

My database is in MongoDB and consists of video game releases, so a game with the same id can repeat more than once in my /releases/ endpoint, but with a different **platform**. For example;

```
"data" : [ {
    "date" : 1524528000000,
    "game" : 253,
    "id" : 1,
    "platform" : 2,
  }, {
    "date" : 1524528000000,
    "game" : 253,
    "id" : 2,
    "platform" : 6
  }, {
    "date" : 1943308800000,
    "game" : 253,
    "id" : 3,
    "platform" : 4,
  }]
```

Please note that the three JSON Objects present are all about the same game **[game=253]**, but each one of them has a different **platform**. Also take notice that the third object has a different release date than the first two.

What I want to accomplish is group my JSON data first by game id then by release date to "uniformize" my data in a way. So in this context, rather than having three JSON Objects, it'll be two objects, like so:

```
"data" : [ {
    "date" : 1524528000000,
    "game" : 253,
    "id" : 1,
    "platform" : [2, 6],
  },{
    "date" : 1943308800000,
    "game" : 253,
    "id" : 0,
    "platform" : [4],
  }]
```

The second object (initially the third in the first JSON) is not grouped with the first one because it has a different release date than the first two initial JSON Objects.

I want to accomplish this output like in the second JSON. What I have done is I grouped all the JSON objects with the same game ID as one object no matter the release date (Please see my code down below). I want the objects that have the same game id to be grouped up together, but if the same game has a different release date on another platform; I want it to stand alone on its own as an object.

My code:

```
# Important: to sort before grouping
region_list.sort(key=lambda k: k['game'])
# Then use group by with the same key
group = groupby(region_list, lambda k: k['game'])
for game_id, group in group:
    print('id', game_id)
    platforms = []
    date = release_object['date']
    initial_release_object = None
    for release_object in group:
        if initial_release_object is None:
            initial_release_object = release_object
        platforms.append(release_object['platform'])
        print(release_object['date'])
    initial_release_object['platforms'] = platforms
```

Comment: What is `groupby`?

Comment: from itertools import groupby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep track of which keys you have already seen while processing, you can accumulate the platform like:

#### Code:

```
def consolidate_platform(data_to_process):
    already_seen = {}
    return_data = []
    for datum in data_to_process:
        key = datum['date'], datum['game']
        if key in already_seen:
            already_seen[key]['platform'].append(datum['platform'])
        else:
            return_data.append(datum)
            already_seen[key] = datum
            datum['platform'] = [datum['platform']]
    return return_data
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [{
    "date": 1524528000000,
    "game": 253,
    "id": 1,
    "platform": 2,
}, {
    "date": 1524528000000,
    "game": 253,
    "id": 2,
    "platform": 6
}, {
    "date": 1943308800000,
    "game": 253,
    "id": 3,
    "platform": 4,
}]

print(consolidate_platform(data))
```

#### Results:

```
[{'date': 1524528000000L, 'platform': [2, 6], 'game': 253, 'id': 1}, 
 {'date': 1943308800000L, 'platform': [4], 'game': 253, 'id': 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
data = {'data': [{'date': 1524528000000, 'game': 253, 'id': 1, 'platform': 2}, {'date': 1524528000000, 'game': 253, 'id': 2, 'platform': 6}, {'date': 1943308800000, 'game': 253, 'id': 3, 'platform': 4}]}
def clean_data(f):
  def wrapper(d):
    return {'data':list(f(d['data']))}
  return wrapper

@clean_data
def group_data(d):
  for i, [a, b] in enumerate(itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x['date']), key=lambda x:x['date'])):
     yield (lambda x:{'date':a, 'game':x[0]['game'], 'id':i, 'platform{}'.format(['', 's'][len(x) > 1]):[c['platform'] for c in x]})(list(b))

print(group_data(data))
```

Output:

```
{'data': [{'date': 1524528000000, 'game': 253, 'id': 0, 'platforms': [2, 6]}, {'date': 1943308800000, 'game': 253, 'id': 1, 'platform': [4]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with `itertools.groupby`. First, define a key to group the dicts:

```
def group_key(d):
    return d["date"], d["game"]
```

Then iterate over the groups with `enumerate` (this will give you a unique id per game/date).

```
def cleaner(data):
    data = sorted(data, key=sort_key)
    for i, (_, vs) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(data, group_key)):
        # there is always at least one element
        first = next(vs)
        # The first element of the group contains the date, the game, and the first platform. Add the id.
        d = {"date":first["date"], "game":first["game"], "platform":[first["platform"]], "id":i}
        # add the remaining platform
        d["platform"] += [v["platform"] for v in vs]
        yield d
```

Do not forget to pre sort the data. You may also build the dict more succintly

```
        first = next(vs)
        yield {"date":first["date"], 
               "game":first["game"], 
               "platform":[first["platform"]]+[v["platform"] for v in vs], 
               "id":i}
```